# .NET 4.0's Task class - Promise interface?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Is there a promise interface for the `Task` class like jQuery's deferred's `promise` method?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I do not understand what you expect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The TPL, and the Task class, are very different than jQuery's promise.

A `Task` is actually effectively more like the original action.  If you wanted to have something run when the task completed, you'd use a *continuation* on the Task.  This would effectively look more like:

```
Task someTask = RunMethodAsync();
someTask.ContinueWith( t =>
{
   // This runs after the task completes, similar to how promise() would work
});
```

If you want to continue on multiple tasks, you can use `Task.Factory.`[`ContinueWhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321258.aspx) or `Task.Factory.`[`ContinueWhenAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenany.aspx) to make continuations that works on multiple tasks.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you're looking for TaskCompletionSource:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Args>(); 

var obj = new SomeApi();

// will get raised, when the work is done
obj.Done += (args) => 
{
    // this will notify the caller 
    // of the SomeApiWrapper that 
    // the task just completed
    tcs.SetResult(args);
}

// start the work
obj.Do();

return tcs.Task;
```

The code is taken from here: [When should TaskCompletionSource<T> be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316613/real-life-scenarios-for-using-taskcompletionsourcet)

Answer (score 5):

That sounds like a continuation, so use `.ContinueWith(callback)`; or in C# 5.0, simply `await`, i.e.

```
var task = /*...*/
var result = await task;
// everything here happens later on, when it is completed
// (assuming it isn't already)
```

different API, but I *think* it does what you are asking (a little hard to be sure... I'm not *entirely* sure I understand the question)